# TeamCity: building with Gradle to retrieve path to <project name>/build/outputs/apk/*.apk regardless of which project?

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity

We are currently setting up TeamCity with Gradle to build Android Projects and upload them to our in-house web server.
However, in order to upload the apk we would need to get the correct path to the build folder.

What would be the best approach to retrieve the apk from the build folder to extract as artefact, regardless of which project? We would like to use a meta-runner to get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you upload artefact to web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my initial question: I created a simple terminal search for the apk in the build folder sorted by date/last modified:

```
LAST_APK_FILE=`find . -name "*.apk" 2>/dev/null | xargs ls -1tr | tail -n 1`
```

We then copy this apk to a more readable filename:

```
NEW_APK_FILENAME=`echo $( echo "%teamcity.project.id%.apk" | tr " ()&'"! "______" )`
cp $LAST_APK_FILE $NEW_APK_FILENAME
```